# Is there an equivalent for Bootstrap's .container-fluid in Materialize CSS?

Tags: materialize

I'm trying to create a 100% wide grid layout with materialize css. However, the .row class doesn't have a negative margin when it's not inside a .container class. This makes nesting very ugly because it creates new padding for every child .col.

Is there an equivalent for Bootstrap's .container-fluid in Materialize CSS?

I have seen an answered post regarding this issue, but it doesn't actually answer the question in a simple nested cols layout.

Comment: I managed to get it all working as intended by adding a .fluid class to the .container with the following CSS: .container.fluid {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .container.fluid > .row {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }

But isn't there a solution to this issue in the framework?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any special class like `container-fluid` in Materializecss.

Responsive grid system in Materializecss has `width: 100%` by default and if you add `container` class to your `<div>`, the `width` will be `70%`.

More info : https://materializecss.com/grid.html